# Where is a full (complete) list of defaults domains and parameters?

Tags: settings, preferences, macos, defaults, plist

I found several long lists with defaults, settings, but never a complete one with a reference to developers.apple.com. Is there any such list to find? If not, which is the longest/systematic/complete list with defaults?

## Update:

I'm interested more in the system administration point of view on the collection of the defaults settings, rather than in the developing an application

## Update2:

Interesting could be something like TinkerTool collection in the form of Application, but using only the terminal

## Update3:

e.g. all defaults keys from `NSGlobalDomain`

Comment: I'm still not quite sure I understand. [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/300321023/Docs-en/pgs/0240-Standalone.html) does seem to be using only the Terminal. It is called `TinkerTool System Release 2 Standalone Utility` and it seems to be running in Terminal. Is [this](http://www.bresink.com/osx/300321023/Docs-en/pgs/0240-Standalone.html) what you were looking for?

Comment: didn't found that page before. but I don't see a defaults manipulation there

Comment: Static, please take a look at my update and see if it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.real-world-systems.com/docs/defaults.txt.html) is the list of all defaults parameters that [I think] you are looking for.

[Here](http://www.real-world-systems.com/docs/defaults.1.html) is the link I got it from.

Looks something like this, but a **lot** longer :) :

> NSBundleIdentifier = "com.apple.Stickies"; NSBundlePath =
>   "/Applications/Stickies.app"; NSKeyEquivalent = { English = Y; default
>   = Y; };
>                       NSMenuItem =                     { English = "Make New Sticky Note"; default = "Make Sticky"; };
>                       NSMessage = makeStickyFromTextService;
>                       NSPortName = Stickies;
>                       NSSendTypes =                     ( NSStringPboardType, NSRTFPboardType, NSRTFDPboardType);
>                       NSUUID = <8d4e24fb c97345b3 89d26400 baabea39>;
>                                               },

### If The Above Is Not Sufficient

Try searching for what you want [here](http://secrets.blacktree.com/?showapp=NSGlobalDomain). It is a database of hidden, secret settings for NSGlobalDomain.

Comment: thanks for the answer and for the remark, but I'm currently interested more in the system administration point of view on the collection of the defaults settings. (updated the post)

Comment: awesome! :) I think they are still not all (or not all actuall - it's related to 10.7.4) but still its really great collection!

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: :) this is what I already found and noticed in the post with (many/several lists). But they are only user collection without any references (and there is not so many NSGlobalDomain settings listed). Still thank you very much for trying to help!

Comment: Well, it was a good exercise for me as well. I have use for a compilation such as this. I think O'Reilly should adapt a Pocket Reference on this subject. (I'd write one myself if I had the time.)

Comment: hm, I think I saw somewhere a book by O'Reilly "osx for the unix geeks". a good point to search references